# Compressed NFT's account

Tags: nft, metadata, compression

I'm new to blockchain development and don't get how it works. So, when I mint an usual NFT, I can see it's collection's page on solscan, even if it doesn't have a collection. When I click on compressed NFT, I just see an empty account (probably the mint cnft's account). So, I read the official solana docs and found some thing as a mint extensions. Can I add metadata-pointer to a compressed nft? Or do I get the whole conception wrong?

Comment: Compressed NFTs are a totally different product from the mint extensions in token-2022. I'm pretty sure compressed NFTs only support the legacy token program and metaplex metadata, so you won't be able to use any of the token-2022 extensions with compressed NFTs